# Button Click Affect Parent, But Not the Whole Class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just started learning to code so this may be a stupid question. I am trying to make it so that when you press a button(image), it changes the css of the div it is in, without affecting the whole class, only the div belonging to that class that the button is in. I'm trying to do this without having to use IDs, in order to make the code more flexible.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrU42/

This is what I have so far and it works great aside from the fact that you need to click the div itself to change its css. This doesn't seem very intuitive, so I'm trying to make that you must press the button in the top left of the div, the div's css is changed. My first guess goes like this:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("largeDiv").toggleClass("smallDiv");
});
```

Obviously, this doesn't work because it toggles the class of the box. My second guess is to change it so that, when the button is clicked, it affects the button's parent like this:

```
$(".box").click(function() {
    $(this:parent).toggleClass("largeDiv").toggleClass("smallDiv");
});
```

This doesn't work, though, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `:parent` selector in jQuery, You're looking for **[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".box").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("largeDiv smallDiv");
    });
});
```

Please note that you can use provide multiple classes to toggle inside `.toggleClass()` as well as you're able to include jQuery directly from `jsFiddle` by choosing jQuery version from `Frameworks & Extensions` tab.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrU42/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

`:anything` represents a pseudo selector for example `:checked`. But there is no `:parent` pseudo selector in jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".box").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("largeDiv").toggleClass("smallDiv");
    });
});
```

You need to call .parent() to get the `largeDiv`